How can I make an instance-level dictionary in a PropertyGroup class?
I have a class that inherits PropertyGroup
I have lots of properties inside, and besides I want it to have also a dictionary that store different keys and values for each instance.
the problem is that all the instances share the same keys and values, so if I edit or append something of one instance, it's affect all of them. and I can't defined it as a instance-level because of the fact that PropertyGroup don't allow using __init__.
is there anything I can do to make the dictionary instance-level variable?
example code for my class:
class code_example(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    string_prop: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    int_prop: bpy.props.IntProperty()

    dictionary = {}


Use the custom properties.

import bpy


class SceneSettingItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Test")
    
    @property
    def my_dict(self):
        my_dict = self.get('my_dict', None)
        if my_dict is None:
            self['my_dict'] = {}
            
        return self['my_dict']


bpy.utils.register_class(SceneSettingItem)

bpy.types.Scene.my_settings = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)


my_item = bpy.context.scene.my_settings.add()
my_item.my_dict['value'] = 123

my_item = bpy.context.scene.my_settings.add()
my_item.my_dict['abc'] = None


for my_item in bpy.context.scene.my_settings:
    print(my_item.my_dict.to_dict())


